# Multi-factorial PCA analysis extracting the maximum loading values

Tags: r

I have a data set with multiple species, and about 400 variables. I would like to perform a Princpal Component Analysis (PCA) on each individual species, and return the variable with the highest loading value per species.

To make a replicate dummy set of my data:

```
set.seed(45)
pcadata <- data.frame(matrix(sample(10, 26746*400, TRUE), ncol=400))
cbind(pcadata,"Species")
```

One problem I have encountered is having different sample sizes for a given Species. So for example, I might have 250 samples of Species A, and 520 of Species B. I therefore have to use the `prcomp` function, because I have more variables than samples. Therefore, if Species A (spA) were in the data.frame, I would first have to subset the data:

```
pcadata.s<-pcadata[,2:401]

pca<-prcomp(pcadata.s,cor=T,scale=T)
al<-abs(pca$rotation)                    #Absolute value of the loading value
loads<-sweep(al,2,colSums(al),"/")       #Percentage contribution
loads.mtx<-as.data.frame(loads)
rownames(loads.mtx)[apply(loads.mtx,2,which.max)] #Return the Column-name with the max value
```

I would like, without having to sub-sample each time, get the Column names per each Species groupings, for example:

```
Species  PC1     PC2      PC3      PC4      PC5
 spA      V3     V100     V287     V2       V65
 spB      V78    V197     V310     V23      V333 
........
```

Just realized: I need to select the components I am interested in, preferably 95% of explained variance, and maybe I will try for 99% also...but I will have to include the code for that.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: My advice would be to keep your dummy set a little smaller people can check out the problem without having to deal with the computation load. Also `cbind(pcadata, "Species")` won't do anything useful, and your columns lack species name.

Comment: @Manetheran, Thanks. I wanted to include the Species grouping merely as reference. I did not want to stray from the main problem I have which is trying to get the required output without having to manually subset for each group of Species. I tried out my code on a very small dummy set, but I completely understand your comments about keeping the dummy set small. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep the species name as a variable in the data frame you may use `ddply` in the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
# create data with a species variable
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, size = 50, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
df$species <- rep(1:2, each = 5)

# run pca and massage data per species
df2 <- ddply(.data = df, .variables = .(species), function(x){
  pca <- prcomp(x[ , 1:5], cor = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
  load <- abs(pca$rotation) 
  prop_load <- apply(load, 2, function(x) x/sum(x))
  max_load <- rownames(prop_load)[apply(prop_load, 2, function(x) which.max(x))]
  max_load2 <- data.frame(t(max_load))
  names(max_load2) <- colnames(load)
  return(max_load2)
}
)
df2

# species PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5
# 1       1  X1  X2  X4  X3  X5
# 2       2  X2  X1  X3  X2  X5
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I will definitely have a look at the `plyr` package. You have definitely saved me some lines of coding. Much appreciated.

Comment: I am very sorry. I HAD NO IDEA this was possible. Please accept my most humble apologies, and thanks again for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Hi Henrik, I am trying to run this function on my data (which is numeric), but I keep getting an error `Error in eval.quoted(.variables, data) : 
  envir must be either NULL, a list, or an environment.` or `Error in if (empty(.data)) return(.data) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
`. I have searched for converting numeric to integer, but it replaces my values with 0's and 1's. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to apply the `prcomp` function over subsets of your data. Theres no native way of handling this (that I know of).

You could try something along these lines:

```
species <- unique(colnames(pcadata))
pcaresults <- list()
for (sp in species) {
  spIndices <- which(colnames(pcadata) == sp)
  pcaresults[sp] <- prcomp(pcadata[,spIndices], cor=T,scale=T)
}
```

This will give you a list where each element is the return result from the PCA on that species. You could change the loop, or format the return list, to only obtain the data you want.

Comment: @ Manetheran, Thanks a million. I will definitely give it a go. Your code has helped me understand how to use a list in a loop, I have been struggling with that for a while now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help! R can be confusing at first!